# Error in making Administrator account

Tags: windows-8

[image]

i am unable to create administrator account.with the following command it is showing system error 5 has occoured as in photo. I tried only that command if you know other i would be greatful to you please suggest any idea to make a account.
regards

Comment: run the cmd.exe as admin

Answer (score 2):

System Error 5 means that the commandline process does not have administrative privileges.

To solve the problem, close this command prompt window, and open a new instance, but run it as Administrator.

The quickest way to do this is as follows:

Press <kbd>Win</kbd> (to access the startmenu) and type `cmd`

Now instead of pressing enter or selecting the program, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and it will launch command prompt as administrator.

The next screen will ask permission to run Command Prompt as administrator (unless UAC is disabled) and your command prompt will start in `C:\Windows\System32` instead of your own user folder.

If you now try the command, it will work.

Comment: i am unable to run command prompt as administrator because i don't have access to C drive

Comment: So you need to get permission. But I think your command is a way to gain access to the system and it would be foolish from Microsoft if they allowed a command to create an account with full access to be made without having that access in the first place. So this is one of those: you can only do it if you already could do it otherwise. If you don't have the permission, you won't be able to circumvent security.